# Call PHP file via BATCH

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, batch-file

I want to create a BATCH File which is like a Cron Job. It runs in a loop and should call a PHP File which is on my server. I don't want my BATCH file to open hundrets of Web Browser Windows.

Any idea how to get this working?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using Windows then u can use Windows event scheduler...

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: @user3414272 did my answer not work? mark it as accepted if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your batch file, you can call `pathToYourPhpInstallation/php yourphpfile.php` the same way you can do it in your command line / terminal.
For instance, if by BATCH you mean a .bat file on your windows system, it could look like this:

```
dosomething.bat:
c:
cd C:\www\myApp\backend
delete *.tmp
"C:\php\php.exe" ajax-backend.php
```

If you have a mor complex site that you need to start or do something with, some of the common test frameworks (i.e. [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)) are able, even thou not intended to do so.